# C++/rapidjson - unable to iterate over array of objects

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I have the following json:

```
{
    "data": {
        "10": {
            "id": 11,
            "accountId": 11,
            "productId": 2,
            "variantId": 0,
            "paymentMethod": "PayPal",
            "amount": "9.99",
            "status": "confirmed",
            "created_at": "2019-12-02T21:55:30.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2019-12-02T21:56:57.000000Z"
        },
        "12": {
            "id": 14,
            "accountId": 69,
            "productId": 3,
            "variantId": 0,
            "paymentMethod": "PayPal",
            "amount": "19.99",
            "status": "confirmed",
            "created_at": "2019-12-05T09:09:21.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2019-12-05T09:14:09.000000Z"
        },
       }
}
```

Here is how I parse it:

```
// parse JSON response
rapidjson::Document parsed_response;
parsed_response.Parse(readBuffer.c_str());

const rapidjson::Value& data = parsed_response[ "data" ];
for ( rapidjson::Value::ConstMemberIterator iterator = data.MemberBegin(); iterator != data.MemberEnd(); ++iterator )
{
    std::cout << iterator->name.GetString() << std::endl;
}
```

This gives following output:

```
10
12
```

I am unable unfortunately to get into objects 10 and 12 and get the `accountId` or any other member of objects 10 and 12.

How can I get inside these objects and retrieve any data there like accountId, productId, variantId etc.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iterator->name` refers to the bit before the `:` in the json, to get at the other side you need `iterator->value`.

```
for ( auto & data : parsed_response[ "data" ].GetObject() )
{
    std::cout << data.name.GetString()
              << data.value["accountId"].GetString()
              << data.value["productId"].GetString()
              << data.value["variantId"].GetString()
              << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over only the first level of the array. You should use `IsObject()` function to determine if the field itself contains an object. After that, as it is already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50458088/9560245), you can use `GetObject()` function to access the internal fields of the nested JSON object using the nested loop:

```cpp
if(iterator->IsObject())
{
   for (auto& nested : iterator->GetObject()){ ... }
}
```

Comment: No member named 'IsObject' in 'rapidjson::GenericMember<rapidjson::UTF8<>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>>'